# Weblogic caching problems

Tags: caching, weblogic, wlst

I'm writing a WLST script to deploy an application with WebLogic 11g. The problem is that when I deploy an application (version `A`), undeploy it, then deploy version `B`, it deploys version `A`.

If I try to solve this by deleting the `tmp/_WL_user/appname/` folder, it then won't deploy `A` or `B` because it looks in the tmp folder for the application (and fails because I cleared it out). I'm using the nostage option, so I don't understand why it's caching anything.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the undeploy of Version A was not successful and Version B was never deployed.

Not sure what you have in the WLST script, could you try with the following:

```
# let's say the appName is testApp
# can move all of these properties to a props file
appName='testApp'
appPath='/scratch/user/testApp.war'
appTarget='AdminServer'
username='weblogic'
password='weblogic1'
adminURL='t3://hostname:adminport'

# start deploy/undeploy code
connect (username, password, adminURL)
for app in cmo.getAppDeployments():
    currAppName = app.getName()
    if currAppName == appName :
        print('Application' + appName + ' already exists, undeploying...')
        undeploy(appName)
        # sleep is just to make sure that we don't attempt deploy immediately i.e before server is finished with undeploying
        # more like a safe side one, may not be required also
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(60000)
print('Now deploying ' + appName)
deploy(appName, appPath, appTarget)
disconnect()
```