# Deploying applications to Web Logic production Server

Tags: oracle, webserver, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am here to get some expert advice on deploying applications to WebLogic Production Server.
Is it a best practice to use Admin Server Console for deploying and redeploying applications in production. Actually I am deploying to a cluster having two managed server instances.

I have encountered this issue while i am redeploying application in the production. When i am deleting existing .ear file and adding updated .ear file will put the updated .ear file into prepared state. I can not make it Active state using Admin Server Console. If i try it will through some exceptions. But after some time it automatically goes in to active state, but i don't know what is happening inside. Sometimes i restart the server to make it active. Could anybody explain me what is the procedure when deploying application and redeploying applications in weblogic

Thanks in advance for any Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally WLST (WebLogic Scripting Tool) is used to deploy the applications. Administration Console can also be used to deploy/upgrade the applications but if there are many environments that need to be upgraded then WLST (which works like a command line tool) is much better option.

Get an overview of [WLST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/using_wlst.htm) to know how to use it to [deploy/undeploy/upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396043/weblogic-caching-problems/12401199#12401199)  applications.

Comment: Yes, In my question, I mean deploying to managed servers using Admin Server Console

Comment: Ok. Eventually WLST/Admin Console uses the same APIs to deploy/upgrade an application. So if you are seeing errors/exceptions probably they are related to your application and/or WebLogic Server configuration. Could you post the stack trace/errors/exceptions that you get while upgrading? Also give a shot with WLST.

Comment: @Mani Ant build scripts can be used for deployment and re-deployment to WLS? And is that a best practice for production environments?

Comment: @Polppan [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/understanding.htm#i1057851) puts `wldeploy ant task` under 'Deployment Tools for Developers'. So I don't think its a best practice for production environments.

Answer (score 2):

Check out "Understanding WebLogic Server Deployment" and the "Redeploying Applications in a Production Environment".  There are different factors that affect redeployment of an application which you might be running into.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/understanding.htm#i1057116

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/redeploy.htm#g1039635

Additionally, there is a WebLogic Plug-in for Maven in more recent WebLogic releases that you can use for deployments in conjunction with Maven.